# An item with the same key has already been added error

Tags: wpf, mvvm, key

I know the error is a common one but i'm not sure how to solve this.

my scenario is this:

- click button on window 1, window 2 will show (populates text boxes).
- finish transaction on window 2 (save data).
- click BACK button on window 2 (closes window 2, opens window 1).
- again, click button on window 1 to open and populate data on window 2.
- error fires. An item with the same key has been added.

Comment: What item? What key? We need some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are adding data to something in Window 2 that is shared across the entire application, or all instance of Window 2. When you enter Window 2 for a second time and populate your data, you are likely adding the data into a `Dictionary` that has already been added. Hence the message "An item with the same key has already been added".

My advice: put a break point in the code where you populate the data, and check the values contained within the `Dictionary` (if you have used one and have access to it). Then check the data you are adding and you should find the replication.

Alternately, there are various ways to prevent duplicate entries being added.

1. Clean the `Dictionary` when you have finished with it the first time - this way you only add the data in once (unless you have duplicate entries in your source data).
2. See if the key exists within the `Dictionary` before adding the entry. You can do this by using `if (mSomeDictionary.ContainsKey(someEntryKey))`/
3. If you simply want to use the latest values, you can just override the data keyed with a certain object. You can do this by using something like: `mSomeDictionary[someEntryKey] = someValue;`. If the entry key doesn't already exist, a new entry will automatically be added.

If none of the above helps you at all, post the code where the error occurs and include the Stack Trace from within the thrown exception and we can look into it further.

Comment: When you say Dictionary, does it refer to the Resource Dictionary which contains some styling stuff for my controls? How do I deal with it then?

Comment: I was actually referring to a standard `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) for the MSDN Documentation.

Comment: System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value) at BioFramework.Util.Properties.GetProviderFromAssemblyList(List`1 assembly) at Framework.Biometric.() at Framework.Biometric.Initialize(String providerPath) at .Framework.Biometric.Initialize() at Window2..ctor(Boolean onResumeMode) in (projectpath)\window2.xaml.cs:line 63 at method(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) in (projectpath)\Window2ViewModel.cs....

Comment: here's the stack trace.. it is somehow caused by a third party library.. but i dont know how to bypass it.. or how to get around with the dictionary..

Comment: Is any of the code referenced in that stack trace your code? I'm assuming the BioFramework is the 3rd party code, but what about Window2ViewModel.cs?

Comment: sorry for the super late reply, but for this issue, i figured a way to set a flag to true once the third party library has already been instantiated throughout the life cycle of the application so it won't load again while still inside the same life cycle. thanks again.